# Python+Selenium, браузер пишет неправильную дату в куки

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

Дело вот в чем. 
Пишу на python3 приложение, имитирующее действие пользователя в соц сети (бот). Нужно, как я понял, по возможности авторизовываться через куки, дабы не попасть в бан. Использую Selenium + ChromeDriver. Гет-запросы посылает, куки парсит в файл, все вроде в порядке, кроме одной вещи - оно в поле "expiry" в куках пишет полный бред (даты 2024 или вообще 2052-х годов при конвертации из timestamp в datetime), из-за чего при попытках считать из файла записанные куки и поместить их в браузер вылетает invalid expiry. Вот код:

```
        import pickle
        import selenium
        import os
        import time
        import datetime
        import selenium.common.exceptions as excp
        from selenium import webdriver
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_argument('--window-size=900,768')
        chromeBrowser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        chromeBrowser.implicitly_wait(10)
        chromeBrowser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to- 
        convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime')
        chromeBrowser.implicitly_wait(3)
        allCookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
        for cookie in allCookies:
        print(cookie)

        pickle.dump(chromeBrowser.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

Использую Хром-драйвер для 75й версии.
(примечание на всякий пожарный) Для того чтобы не вылетало в первый раз нужно конечно же закомментировать цикл for и только после первого запроса его откомментить, когда файл с куками будет создан. Я делал по разным примерам (типа вот этого https://github.com/kricha/insta_browser/blob/master/insta_browser/auth.py), у людей кажется все добавлялось без проблем... Погуглил эту ошибку - пока не нашел ответа. Может знаете, как эту проблему решить?
[[image: Скрин работы]]expiry при конвертации в datetime получает астрономические даты[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsrB.png)

UPD: Все, разобрался в чем трабл. Оказывается просто хромдрайвер для версии 75 - баганутый, скачал 74й - и все работает как надо!

Comment: Очень большое время жизни куки обычно понимается как " живёт вечно". И это ок, по крайней мере не запрещается

Comment: @m9_psy пожалуй да, я как и подобает любому добропорядочному нубу не знал что такие даты это в общем то норма, сейчас посмотрел как выглядят нормальные куки и пробил лицо фейспалмом. Просто при добавлении нового кука в браузер в цикле for оно вылетает. Может быть, оно просто timestamp не переводит автоматически в дату/время, хотя странно конечно, ведь в примерах у других людей все работало...

Comment: в идеале сообщества, если вы решили свою проблему, напишите в ответ, то как вы к этому пришли и как исправили. А то получается, что ответ найден, а вопрос не закрыт

Comment: @AtachiShadow да, извините, я решил проблему. Проблема была просто в драйвере, пришлось ставить другой.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была просто в драйвере, пришлось ставить другой. 
P.s все, извините уважаемые модеры, проморгал как-то эту функцию)